# "transform: translateX(-50%)" with "position: absolute" and "left: 50%" results in scrollbar in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, transform

I want to position a `main` container in the middle of the viewport.

The container is absolutely positioned, because I want it to fill up the whole vertical space by using `position: absolute;top: 0;bottom: 0` (I know that I could achieve a similar effect by using `height:100%` on `html, body, main`, but as soon as the content of `main` exceeds the full height, the `main` container won't stretch at these exact 100%, which is not what I want).

So to position the absolutely positioned `main` container in the middle of the viewport, I rely on `transform: translateX(-50%)`, which works painlessly - except in Internet Explorer, which adds an unwanted horizontal scrollbar!

Take a look at this pen:

http://codepen.io/jmuheim/pen/wCzcr

Is there any way to prevent the horizontal scrollbar? `overflow-y: none` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue some days ago. It appears that it's a bug and the easier way to fix it, it's to position your element from the `right` instead of the `left`.

To use your example, the result will be :

```
main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

You can try it live there : https://jsfiddle.net/julienvanderkluft/3udza0te/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change 2 things.

```
right: 50%;
transform: translateX(50%)
```

Comment: Why is the `translateY` needed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center your element horizontally and vertically, you can use something like this as well.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>Center</span>
  </div>
</div>
```